# MVVM stuck event hook

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, memory-leaks

I'll start by saying this is a very simplified example, my problem is in a much larger project so while a restructure of what I'm doing would be the best way it's not an option, I'm looking for something I can add to this example to solve the issue at the bottom if possible.

I have 2 `viewmodels`(`Person` and `Address`).

*Person.cs*

```
public class Person : ViewModelBase
{
}
```

*Address.cs*

```
public class Address : ViewModelBase
{
    public Address() : base()
    {
       Model.OnModelChanged += Model_OnModelChanged;
    }

    private void Model_OnModelChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }        
}
```

As you can see, `Address` on construction is hooking in to the model, this is the **important part**!

The views for these two objects are.

*Person.xaml*

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Person}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Person}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="Person"/>
                    <local:Address/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

*Address.xaml*

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Address}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Address}">
                    <TextBlock Text="Address"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The `Person` view introduces the `Address` viewmodel on it's own, If I add 2 instance of `Person` to a list on the main window, the view will create 2 new instances of `Address`, this is by design and great.

My problem is, if you remove one of the instances of Person from the collection you're left with 2 instances of person and address, one that's held in memory by the event hook.

If a viewmodel has been introduced to the visual tree by a view and hooks events how do you get rid of them?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I appreciate that your question isn't just the usual code dump. But you have oversimplified. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. Also, I don't really see the need for all the images; I don't think it's necessary to see the memory profiler windows to understand that you want to unsubscribe some event handler.

Comment: You need to track adds and removals from the collection/container/???, and on add you need to subscribe to the event and on removal you need to unsubscribe.  Or, at least that's what one would normally do. What you're doing is kinda weird, to the point where I don't fully understand it.  Whoever is doing the addition/removal needs to control this subscription process. If you're doing it in some way that does not permit for this, *stop hitting yourself in the head with that hammer*. Refactor.

Comment: What exactly is your issue? It is to be expected, that the objects will remain in memory (assuming you have no other references to it) until the GC decides to collect it. If you want to specifically release unmanaged resources of an object, you have to implement the disposable pattern and call the dispose method

Comment: bit busy in work at the mo to properly update this question to give more details but basically there is a list bound to a collection of Persons when I add a person to it, it appears on the screen with their address, when I remove it both person and address are stuck in memory by the event hook in address, I was hoping someone had a solution that I could include without a rewrite of a very large project.

Comment: There is no relation between the two entities? Like a `Person` has an `Address`? In this case, the address view model should be gone, if you remove the person it is contained in.

Comment: no the address was introduced by the View for person, it makes more sense in the full application. The address is hooking in to the model to get it's own updates, I basically need to unhook that event somehow when the person is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Implement IDisposable and remove the listener to OnModelChanged, what I'm unsure of is if you need to implement idisposable in both classes, and in the person class call dispose on address. BUT you definately have to remove the listener in the address Dispose method.

Another option is to look at the Weak event pattern, but I am unfamiliar with it.